# How can I clean HOME folder in linux?

Tags: linux, cache, maintenance

There is a way to clean in a controlled way the $HOME folders than usually save cache files?

E.g: I have a `.config` folder with more than 300MB. How can I clean it?. Is there a program that can be used to control the saved files? In `.mozilla` folder you can clean up using the Firefox options.

Comment: One that works with all applications, no. Note that the cache files should be stored in *.cache*, not *.config*. In the case of web browser, a large directory in *.config* is usually due to the browser's history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org/) is a program that supports the configuration directories of many programs and is able to delete things that aren't quite necessary (bleachbit is similiar to ccleaner on windows, if you happen to know that).

At least Ubuntu has it in it's repositories.

Comment: You can see on repology, which distribution provides Bleachbit packages. https://repology.org/metapackage/bleachbit/versions

Answer (score 4):

In the $HOME/.config folder there are files created by many different programs, and as such there is no easy way to manage them all.

These files should be created/managed/removed by each single application, and deleting them can (will) result in loss of data (personal configurations in this case).

Being that all the data contained should be configuration data, this folder should not contain a lot of data, 300MB is quite a lot of config.

You can enquire which subfolder contains most of the data by using the command:

> du -sh ~/.config/*

and you can see by yourself which folder has grown out of control.

Comment: ok...I understand know:  278M .config/chromium

Comment: On my work PC I got most of my data under ".config/google-chrome/Default/Session Storage", seems like chrome/chromium does put cache data into the .config directory, which is IMO not correct.

Comment: See this answer about cleaning up your .cache subdirectory in your home folder https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208908/is-it-safe-to-remove-cache